# open file depending on whether it's .gz or not

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm trying to figure out what the best way of opening a python file is based on its type.

For example, I've got something basic like this but it just doesn't seem 'pythonic' to me and I feel like in some way it can be refactored and written more cleaner;

```
def openfile(filename):
    if read_file_from_top:
        if not filename.endswith('.gz'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
                for line in infile:
                   # do something
        else:
            with gzip.open(filename, 'r') as infile:
                for line in infile:
                   # do something
    elif read_file_from_bottom:
        if not filename.endswith('.gz'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    # do something
        else:
            with gzip.open(filename, 'r') as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    # do something
```

Would there be a better way to do this, maybe using a generator? Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between the `read_file_from_top` branch and the `read_file_from_bottom` branch?  And you should fix you indentation (assuming that it's all supposed to be one function).

Comment: The indenting was automatic on stackoverflows editor, some reason it doesn't pick up the function. I'll fix it though. The `read_file_from_top` and `read_file_from_bottom` read the file from the top or the bottom, its basically going through a bunch of dates in chronological order, depending on input it may be faster to read from the top rather than bottom. But this is just an example for the dilemma I'm facing.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Tagc The `# do something` part of this code would make this code considered example code and closed on CR. If it weren't for that then it could be a good CR question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should separate the opening and the reading:

```
def openfile(filename, mode='r'):
    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        return gzip.open(filename, mode) 
    else:
        return open(filename, mode)

with openfile(filename, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
       # do something
```

Comment: good answer, I wanted to edit and remove the colon after "mode)", which would produce an error but cannot make a 1 character edit.

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this is at least a little better:

```
import gzip


def file_line_gen(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        open_fn = gzip.open
    else:
        open_fn = open

    with open_fn(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line


for line in file_line_gen('data.gz'):
    # do something here
    print repr(line)
```

Comment: I would have used a ternary, but yes, it's better.

Comment: Respecting differences of `read_file_from_top`  and `read_file_from_bottom` this is only half an answer.

Comment: @ppasler the code he provided is identical between the two branches.  Without more information, it's unclear what to put there.

Comment: This should be `rb` instead of `r` to have the result be a bytes-like object for both cases. Then you should do a `line.decode("utf-8")` or whatever is needed to convert to `str`.

Comment: @slhck The assumption was that this was Python 2 at the time, not Python 3.  Plus it was more about code/logic organization.  But it could be changed to work with Python 3 by having `file_line_gen()` accept an `encoding` and then passing that along to `open` or `gzip.open` (they both accept an encoding--at least in more recent versions of Python 3).

Comment: Yes, I assumed that this was Python 2. Just leaving that here for the sake of making this future-proof (and I guess it'd be backwards-compatible as well). `gzip.open` does not default to text, so explicitly specifying the encoding is quite necessary.

Comment: @slhck The encoding trick doesn't work for Python 2. :-(  We'd have to do as you suggest and convert line by line to have something that is compatible.

Comment: Will this open the file for each line ?

Comment: @Kimi No.  It opens the file once and keeps it open until you're done iterating.  The `yield` effectively causes execution to pause while the top level loop uses the line, and when the loop needs the next result, execution picks up and reads the next line, and yields the new line.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using a predefined list of crucial functions:

```
def processFile(filepath):
    with [open, gzip.open][0 if not filepath.endswith('.gz') else 1](filepath, 'r') as fh:
        if read_file_from_top:
            # do something
        elif read_file_from_bottom:
            # do something
```